# On Windows 7, how can I make the Start Menu search feature include matches from within words, not just the start of the word?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, windows-search

I have a program installed called WinSCP.  When I press the Windows key and type "SCP", I get "No items match your search."  Is there a configuration option I can set somewhere, so that this item will be found?

I'm not looking for a specific solution for this particular program, but something general, so that if there's a program named XYZ, I can find it via the Start Menu search by entering YZ.

**EDIT TO ADD**: I'm looking for a "set-it and forget-it" type of configuration change, so that within-word searching happens always, automatically.  I don't want to have to type a * before every query.  Apparently this wasn't clear from what I wrote above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For searching `XYZ` just type `*YZ` or `*Z` . It works in start menu search and window search.

Comment: This functionality has existed since DOS. You can also use `?` to match a single character, instead of `*` which matches 0 or more characters.

Comment: This is a nice feature I didn't know about, but it doesn't actually answer the question as I've asked it.   What I'd like is a way to not have to type the * before the search term.  To set something once, and from then on have every query implicitly prepended by *

Comment: (I up-voted you anyway though -- that is a cool, good-to-know-about feature)